# Resta en Django views

Tags: python, django

Estoy realizando un inventario, y tengo parte del código funcionando correctamente:

```
def add_art_view(request, pk, template_name='invstock/art_form.html'):
    id = get_object_or_404(Stock, pk=pk)
    form = StockForm(request.POST or None, instance=id)

    context = {
        'form': form
    }

    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        messages.success(request, ('Register Edited Successfully'))
        return redirect('invstock:art_list_view')

    return render(request, template_name, context)
```

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
        <h2><a href="{% url 'invstock:art_list_view' %}">ART FORM</a></h2>
            <form method="post">{% csrf_token %}
                 <div class="form-group">
                     <label>Cantidad</label>{{ form.cantidad}}
                     <label>Cantidad a debitar</label>{{ form.var_resta}}
                     <label>Name</label>{{ form.name}}
                     <label>ID</label>{{ form.id}}
                 </div>

                 <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
            </form>

{% endblock %}
```

Mi intención es restar el campo CANTIDAD menos el campo VAR_RESTA pero desde las views, y almacenar el valor resultante en el campo CANTIDAD, algo así como
CANTIDAD = CANTIDAD - VAR_RESTA, he dilatado por semanas esto, ya que en toda la investigación, videos, cursos, no he logrado encontrar la respuesta, solo se puede analizar como hacerlo desde el template, pero no es lo que necesito.

Comment: Hola, pueds poner tu modelo o tu forms.py ?

Comment: Has intentado crear un filtertag para restar? Puedes usar el templatetag de `with` para asignar la variable

Answer (score 0):

Para recoger los valores de esos parámetros en el `views.py` podrías obtenerlos con `form.cleaned_data.get('cantidad')` despues del `form.is_valid()`, los restas, asignas el valor a la variable del modelo y lo guardas.